# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop when I trying to change the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(12);

  return (
    <>
     <h1>Number value is: {number}</h1>
     <div className="btn btn-success" onClick = {() => setNumber(number + 1)}>Add</div>
     <div className="btn btn-danger" onClick = {setNumber(number - 1)}>Sub</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I change change `number` using `onClick = {() => setNumber(number + 1)}` everything is ok but when I use `onClick = {setNumber(number - 1)}` I've got an error

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
> prevent an infinite loop.

Explain to me please why I've got an error and **what difference between these callings**? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onClick = {() => setNumber(number + 1)}` This creates a function, that will be called on click event.

`onClick = {setNumber(number - 1)}` Here you call function right now, in process of creation App object. That results to setState => reRender => calling again, so infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the setNumber function to onClick actually runs it causing a re-render everytime the div is rendered.

Passing it as a arrow function, passes the function object without executing it, until the onClick method is called.

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 1):

Just do what you did for your addition in your substraction.
With your current syntax in the substraction, your set state is gonna be called infinitely because you are calling the function directly, you need a function returning this function like you did for your addition.

Comment: I've got but I want to understand the difference between these two methods